# ask php 5.3 .htaccess doesnt work but it works on php 5.5 (other hosting service)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Dear Mr Expert Programmer,

I have a little problem with rewrite rule in a xxx hosting provider. I've asked the administrator about the configuration of their server configuration and the mod_rewrite is on.
This is a little of my .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^home.html$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^index.html$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^tentang_kami.html$ tentang_kami.php [L]
RewriteRule ^blog.html$ blog.php [L]
RewriteRule ^semua_berita.html$ berita.php?act=default [L]
```

The result was all of those written link is automatically redirected to index.php

in example **mydomain.com/semua_berita.html** should be goes to **berita.php?act=default** but the result is redirected to **index.php**

Is it because of the differences between php server or some other reason?
Because instead of redirect to 404 page it always went to index.php

thanks b4

Comment: `.htaccess` is not related to php in any way. it is an `apache` thing. You need to make sure your apache configuration support both `.htaccess` files and configuration change and `mod_rewrite`. I'm not sure what exactly is the problem here. Your redirect goes to `index.php`, which is what you say that happen. Edit your question to make sure you explain what expect to happen and what actually happen (and is not good).

Comment: dear sir Dekel, sorry for my bad english. The problem was if i go to mydomain.com/tentang_kami.html and any of other links available in my site its always redirected to index.php. I thought that if .htaccess is not been read, those link will shows a 404 not found page instead of index.php. Thanks for your consideration

Comment: Have you tried setting the [RewriteBase](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) directive?